# MySql database version control system

Tags: php, mysql, mono, tarantino

I have PHP, MySQL, and Mono installed.

I've been searching for an equivalent of Tarantino's Database script executable for MySQL and have failed miserably in finding something that will work. I don't want to use Liquibase because I find the dealing with tons of Xml extremely unappealing. I don't want to use DVS,because it seems to be way over kill for what I need. I don't want to install Ruby in order to use migrations either. I want the ability to just execute raw scripts like Tarantinos.

Does anyone know of a good one to use or am I going to have to end up rolling my own?

Comment: Have a look at http://dbv.vizuina.com/. It's not much, but I've been using it for quite some time now. Disclaimer: I made it.

Comment: I actually already looked at that, but seemed a bit over-kill for what I needed. I went ahead and rolled my own which you can see below and it solves all my problems. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Doctrine Migrations http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations.html

I've been using it in one of my projects, and it is working quite nicely. You just maintain php files that are classes that have the sql files to run against the DB. There is one simple table that tracks what version the db is currently on.

Comment: Unfortunately I am had some issues with Doctrine Migrate that I couldn't get past, it doesn't seem to be in a usable state for standalone execution at the moment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004082/doctrine-migrations-there-are-no-commands-defined-in-the-namespace

Comment: Yeah, I had that same problem with it. Forgot about that. There's a pull request on the repo to fix it. The file structure for the dependencies has changed, so the build file for the phar needs to be updated.

Comment: Ah, well feel free to use the one I made. It's sweet, simple, and gets the job done. :)