# Doctrine Migrations: There are no commands defined in the "" namespace

Tags: php, doctrine, migration

I'm trying to setup Doctrine Migrations as a standalone program and am having a little bit of trouble.

I have doctrine-migrations.phar and migrations.yml in the same folder.

migrations.yml contains the following:

```
name: Doctrine Sandbox Migrations
migrations_namespace: DoctrineMigrations
table_name: doctrine_migration_versions
migrations_directory: /home/myusername/myproject/Database/Update
```

Inside /home/myusername/myproject/Database/Update I have a file called Version20130608161001.php which contains the following:

```
namespace DoctrineMigrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;

class Version20130608161001 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function up(Schema $schema)
    {
        echo "Test";
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema)
    {

    }
}
```

When I run the command:

```
php doctrine-migrations.phar -v :migrate
```

I get the following error message:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
There are no commands defined in the "" namespace.

Exception trace:
 () at phar:///home/myusername/Desktop/Doctrine/doctrine-migrations.phar/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:441
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->findNamespace() at phar:///home/myusername/Desktop/Doctrine/doctrine-     migrations.phar/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:468
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->findCommand() at phar:///home/myusername/Desktop/Doctrine/doctrine-migrations.phar/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:184
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///home/myusername/Desktop/Doctrine/doctrine-migrations.phar/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:113
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/myusername/Desktop/Doctrine/doctrine-migrations.phar:59
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your composer.json with this:

```
{
  "require": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master"
  }
}
```

And then update:
*Ensure you have the latest SF stable version in composer.json, in this moment 3.3.0

```
composer update
```

Finally, be sure to enable the bundle in AppKernel.php:

```
new Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had this same problem....

You can run the command as follows:

```
./doctrine-migrations migrations:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problems with symfony 3.4
All my package configuration files from "/config/packages" are ignored by symfony.

I fixed this by editing the files:

```
app/config/config_dev.yml
```

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
    - { resource: '../../config/packages/dev/' } #added this line
```

```
app/config/config.yml
```

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: '../../config/packages/doctrine.yaml' }
    - { resource: '../../config/packages/doctrine_migrations.yaml' }
    - { resource: '../../config/packages/fos_rest.yaml' }
    - { resource: '../../config/packages/jms_serializer.yaml' }
    - { resource: '../../config/packages/security_checker.yaml' }
    - { resource: '../../config/packages/sensio_framework_extra.yaml' }
    - { resource: '../../config/packages/swiftmailer.yaml' }
```

unfortunately it is not possible to set import of all the files in the directory "../../config/packages/" becaus some files cannot be imported in this way.